# Is there a method to generate compilation database in a Yocto Bitbake Project?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, language-server-protocol, kbuild, yocto-layer

This is a complex Yocto & Bitbake Project. I need to build it use `bitbake` command, like `bitbake xx-kernel`. And the `xx-kernel` project looks like the linux kernel, using `kbuild`, `make` toolchains for building.
How can I generate compilation database? I think `bear` may be a good choice. But, how can I use `bear` in the building process?

I try to build the `xx-kernel` project alone, since it is similar to linux kernel. Thus I can use `bear make`. However, to compile `xx-kernel`, a lot of dependences need, like header files or libs in other directory in the project. Therefore, the `make` in `xx-kernel` project failed.

The compilation of `bitbake xx-kernel` is ok. However, `bear bitbake xx-kerkel` is not ok.

Comment: Bitbake itself does other things also beside compilation - it fetches the source, unpacks it, patches it, etc etc... generally you want to stick in this tool just in the compilation step most probably. In case your recipe inherits the kernel class, then you could look around [this line](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/classes-recipe/kernel.bbclass#n395) - could be that you would have to go even deeper in the hierarchy.

Comment: @skandigraun Thank you for your reply. I'll have a try.